# I just want to know is this is correct without a proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be integers. If $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$, then $ab\mid c$.
I say yes but I want to know if I'm correct

Comment: let a=b=c=2....

Comment: true if we also restrict $\gcd(a,b) = 1$

Comment: Would those who down-voted this explain why?  I disagree with the proposal to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$30\mid 60$ and $20\mid 60$ but $(30\cdot20)\nmid 60$.

The statement that if $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$ then $ab\mid c$ is true if $a$ and $b$ have no prime factors in common.  But when they do share common factors, then there are many counterexamples like the one above.